# What's the difference between getProductSingle() and getProduct() in Virtuemart 2 Product model class?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

In VirtueMartModelProduct class there are two methods to get a product object from the database: `getProductSingle()` and `getProduct()`. I'm a bit confused with the code below each method, so I would like to know what's the difference between them and when I have to use `getProductSingle` instead of `getProduct`.

The VirtueMartModelProduct class is at: `administrator\components\com_virtuemart\models\product.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its a bit late, but you can understand it with this.
As the documentation of Virtuemart says

> `getProduct()` function creates a product with the attributes of the
>   parent.

We know in Virtuemart we can make child products leaving some of its parameters that will be taken from parent product.
So we set product

> **Parent** *Price* = $100, *Manufacturer* = 'xyz'.

Now if two child products are created like:

**Child1** is created with blank *Price* and *Manufacturer*

**Child2** is created with its own values *Price* = $250, *Manufacturer* = 'abc'.

> The buyer will finally get to see:
>
> **Child1**  *Price* = $100, *Manufacturer* = 'xyz', taken from its parent.
>
> **Child2**  *Price* = $250, *Manufacturer* = 'abc'.

Use of functions and return data:

for **Child1**: `getProductSingle()`, returns *Manufacturer* = '', on the same hand `getProduct()`, returns *Manufacturer* = 'xyz'.

for **Child2**: both `getProductSingle()` and `getProduct()` returns *Manufacturer* = 'abc' as it is directly set onto that product.

> There are other difference in parameters, as you get `salesPrice` using `getProduct()` but have to calculate final price if you use `getProductSingle()`

Answer (score 0):

When you check the both function you will get the reason, even the name itself sense the function it do.

`getProductSingle()` will collect only one product details.

`getProducts()` will get list of product details.

In more details `getProducts()` collect more than one product details with `getProductSingle()` function.

So you need to get list of product details use `getProducts()`. If you need only one product details then use `getProductSingle()`.

Hope it make sense..

Comment: I'm not asking about `getProducts()`, I'm asking about `getProduct()` (without 's'). Both `getProduct()` and `getProductSingle()` collect one product details but what's the difference between them? Anyway, thanks for the answer!